# Ideas from function/logic/object-oriented programming

Tags: programming-languages

Can someone please point me to articles or books that discusses different programming paradigm (function/logical/OOP)... I am not looking for the syntax details but the ideas that make them good..

for ex: using functional programming we avoid any side-effects.. If I know the idea I could write side effect free program even in a language (OOP) that does not enforce it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Programming Language Pragmatics](http://www.cs.rochester.edu/~scott/pragmatics/) gives a pretty thorough overview of different paradigms.  The book is about language design, so it talks a lot about syntax, semantics, type systems, target architectures, etc.  The newest edition has an entire chapter on logical programming languages and one on functional languages.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, the way to write functional in OOP is to make every member final (pretty much always).  This avoids side-effects, and although I'm not really down with the functional programming, I think since I've started making variables final wherever possible my code has improved--so it's certainly got some benefits.

Comment: Your first part seems to confuse 'functional programming' with 'functional decomposition'. The latter is part of the procedural style, not the functional style. Your second part (defining constants rather than variables), however, is functional programming style.

Comment: Whoops, you're right.  I meant final, not static.

Answer (score 0):

There is a reading list about [programming language concepts here](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ebcpierce/courses/670Fall04/GreatWorksInPL.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

I have started reading "Concepts, Techniques, and Models of Computer Programming" by Peter Van Roy and so far its very good...